# Android app development -create a calendar, coloured indicators on different dates, how do I do thi?

Tags: android

I need to insert a calendar In an android app I am developing 
For example:
On the first Wednesday of October 2015 and each fortnight thereafter - one red indicator (eg a circle) is to be seen on this date.
On the second Wednesday of October 2015 and each fortnight thereafter - one green indicator and one red indicator are shown on this date

I don't know to achieve this, do I use CalendarView? Or something else? What would you recommend?

Comment: try using caldroid..it ieasily customizable according to your needs
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Comment: Thank you Aditya Chauhan, just took a quick look at your link that looks great, just what I am after.

Comment: i am adding it as answer do mark it correct it if it helped.

Comment: There's also a material design port of CalendarView https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: Hi Aditya I am not sure where/ how I accept the answer

Comment: @Mi68 To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

try using caldroid..it ieasily customizable according to your needs github.com/roomorama/Caldroid